# How to resolve RecordTooLargeException in Kafka Producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using **FlinkKafkaProducer08** to send records to Kafka . But sometime I am getting  following exception, even though record that I am printing in error message is too small in size  0.02 MB .

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not forward element to next operator
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not forward element to next operator
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Failed to send data to Kafka: The message is 1513657 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordTooLargeException: The message is 1513657 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration
```

Tried to change max.request.size on producer , but that requires brokers changes to and restart of broker .

Answer (score 2):

There is also a broker setting for max message size:

```
message.max.bytes : 1,000,000 (default)
```

So you will need to restart your brokers -- but this should not be an issue. Kafka is built in a robust way with regard to broker bounces.

Cf. http://kafka.apache.org/082/documentation.html#producerconfigs